# Calculating step increment for gradual speed increase

Tags: math, time

This is a pure mathematics question, I expect.

I have an oscillation object in 3d, and I want to be able to gradually increase its speed over a desired time. An oscillarion cycle has a predefined "speed" or rather duration that the duration that oscillation takes. That speed is only re-calculated between the oscillations, and does not change while the object is moving. There is no delay between oscillations

For example:
Start with: 100 ms per oscillation
End with: 3000 ms per oscillation
Over: 10 seconds

All three numbers should be variable. I can't figure out what math function or technique I need to use here. The problem is that each next oscillation takes more time, so you can't just go something like (3000-100)/10 and add that. Because I will over-shoot the target before 10 seconds expire, and I would like to hit it precisely. I also want the change to be as linear as possible

Ideally, I would arrive at a factor that I add to the speed/duration at the start of each oscillation.

```
Start: 100
Target: 400
Duration: 1000
Factor: 100

100    (total 100)
200    (total 300)
300    (total 600)
400    (total 1000) - we're there!
```

But how to calculate that factor - I can't seem to find the right solution...

Comment: If I understand, what you call factor is in fact what you add at each step?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want to have a universal speed change

Comment: If you add a larger number to the duration, the speed will slow down, and if the number if smaller then the speed will increase, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean harmonic oscillations, then **frequency** might be changed instantly. Frequncy is simpler to use in the description of moving than time periods.

For example, linear dependence:

```
f0 = 1.0/0.1 = 10 (Hz)
f1 = 1.0/3 = 0.333 (Hz)
t0 = 0.1
t1 = 1.0
f(t) = f0 + (t-t0)*(f1-f0)/(t1-t0) = 10 - (t-0.1)*9.667/0.9
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only work with durations. Reach x/y in z seconds. The speed of movement is uniform while the object moves, but recalculates before next movement.